# A picturesque way to be elated by music

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

First I must mention that I am not a native English speaker.

I am trying to describe a sense of delight and being elated after listening to music.
Eventually I came up with "floating with tunes and joy" as I was looking to add a visual/picturesque aspect to it - as it is intended for children.

Does it convey the meaning I want? Is it proper English? 
Is there a common way to phrase and describe such feelings?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, DSCH. While not _ungrammatical_, this is probably zeugma (twinning more concrete 'tunes' with purely abstract 'joy'). It's quite transparent (not at all hard to understand). As to how it sounds ... that's better asked on say Writing.SE. I've heard the form of the metaphor 'carried on a current of joy', but again the twinning with 'music' would sound quirky.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. The word "rapture" has multiple meanings, and is sometimes associated with a joyful feeling accompanying music.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You can't touch a tune.

Comment: Thank you @EdwinAshworth and rajah9 (can only mention one person in a comment)

Comment: @Naomi 'More concrete tunes' = 'rock music'. Seriously, the whole 'abstract ... concrete' simplistic treatment has been found to be severely flawed. Many traditionalists would in fact say 'tunes can be perceived by a sense, hearing, and so "tune" is a concrete noun'. But few grammarians are traditionalists.